# is it possible to extract spectrum (color in general) from an animal

Tags: optics, visible-light, vision

if i may ask....can this be ASAP? :3

my problem:
okay this is going to sound lame, but i was wondering if it is possible to extract color (specifically spectrum) from an animal. 
this question occurred when i was reading the popular my little pony fan-fiction 'the rainbow factory'. in the story scootaloo (main protagonist) fails her flight test, resulting she is sent to the rainbow factory. when at the rainbow factory failed flight-test ponies get (this is were it sounds lame) crushed into the Pegasus device (a machine in which extracts the color (spectrum) from the pony, resulting in a crushed corpse.

so all in all, is it possible? can a color (spectrum) be extracted from an animal (specifically a horse/pony)?

Comment: Ponies who fail the flight test are executed? And harvested for Soylent Rainbow?

Answer (score 1):

Everything scattering light has a characteristic spectrum. The spectrum is defined by the way wherein the particular thing interacts with light, and this is set by the (1) chemical makeup and (2) texture (at the wavelength-of-visible light scale). You cannot change the spectrum without changing one of these two things, either by *e.g.* (1) altering the chemical makeup of the whole object (by burning it, for example), (2) altering the chemical makeup of the surface interacting with light (by painting it with pigment, for example) or by erasing or distorting key textures (removing a diffraction grating, which is what happens when butterflies lose the scales from their wings).

In short, there is no "magic colour fluid" that can be extracted. The scattered spectrum intrinsically belongs to the properties of the surface interacting with light in question.